# Can we say that any Dedekind-finite family of sets has a choice function without AC?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Let $(S_i)_{i \in I}$ be a family of non-empty sets where $I$ is a Dedekind-finite set. Can we say without the Axiom of Choice that this family has a choice function? I know that for any finite family there is a choice function without the use of AC, but I do not know about the Dedekind-finite case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

If $A$ is an amorphous set, then its power set is Dedekind-finite. Therefore there is no choice function which chooses from its non-empty subsets. Since if $\mathcal P(X)\setminus\{\varnothing\}$ has a choice function, then $X$ can be well-ordered.

So if $A$ is amorphous, then we have a Dedekind-finite family without a choice function.

This is not an equivalence. For example, in Cohen's first model, the family of co-finite subsets of $A$, the canonical Dedekind-finite set, is Dedekind-finite. And it does not admit a choice function, since $$A\text{ is D-infinite} \iff\{A\setminus X\mid X\text{ is finite}\}\text{ admits a choice function}.$$

So again, in Cohen's model we have a Dedekind-finite family of sets without a choice function.

In general, given any Dedekind-finite set $X$, we can arrange an extension of the universe where $X$ remains Dedekind-finite, and there is a family of sets indexed by $X$ which does not have a choice function.

Comment: You are so goddamn fast. I was barely starting my proof.

Comment: You're goddamn right.